# отладчик не срабатывает Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, отладка

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str;
            string str2;
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            str2 = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(str2);
           
        }
    }
}
```

Когда нажимаю на F10 отладчик не идет пошагово от точки остановы вниз а сразу выходит из программы.
У меня такое происходит когда в коде есть Console.ReadLine()
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте Debug конфигурацию сборки, уберите галочку "оптимизировать код", если она установлена.

Comment: проверил, галочка не стоит(

Comment: Что если добавить присваивание `string str = "";`, пойдет ли пошагово? Студии нет под рукой, не могу сам проверить.

Comment: че то ничего не получается, как только пошагово дохожу до Console.ReadLine() и нужно вписать какой то текст в консоль ничего не пишется
Только начал интересоваться программированием и уже такое(

Comment: не пойму что не так с этим Console.ReadLine()

Comment: без отладчика все нормально компилируется

Comment: Что значит "ничего не пишется"?

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно, если еще не читали: [Отладка кода для начинающих](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019). Возможно статья ответит на ваш вопрос.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string str2;
            str2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(str2);


           
        }
    }
}

Вот например дохожу до этого места "str2 = Console.ReadLine();" нажимая F10 и мне по логике надо ввести текст, я набираю текст но он в консоли не отображается, я не вижу его

Comment: А вы мышкой ткните в окно консоли, может оно не в фокусе. Студия показывает, что приложение при этом выполняется, или стоит на строке? Если стоит, надо еще раз F10 нажать.

Comment: спасибо, кажется разобрался, совсем еще новичок как вы понимаете((
Но уже сейчас понимаю как здесь все с пониманием относятся и пытаются помочь, еще раз спасибо за ваше внимание